# Wiring washing machine motor

Tags: motor, wiring, induction-motor

first apologize for wrong wording/idioms.

Found an old washing machine motor. It has six terminals, labeled U, V, W, Z, X, Y

Attached to the motor is a capacitor with two terminals, no more wires attached.

Now my questions would be (living in Europe with 230V mains / 400V):

Can this motor be operated using 230V and what would be the wiring including the capacitor?

Can this motor be operated using 400V and what would be the wiring including the capacitor?  (In this case I guess I would use L1, L2 and L3)

[image: See the picture here.]

Edit: I checked the resistance between all terminals. There is no electrical connection  between the upper and lower set of terminals. One set of terminals (Z X Y) has a resistance of ~35 Ohms between any other two terminal (thick wire going into the motor) and the other set of terminals (U, V, W) has a resistance of ~ 7 Ohms (thin wire going into the motor)

Comment: There would be some “pattern” to link the six terminals to connect them appropriately for single or 3 phase operation. Perhaps there is a manufacturers website...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that this is a two-speed, two winding motor. One set of three terminals is for 350 RPM, 0.2 kW operation and the other set is for 2800 RPM, 0.5 kW operation. The first set requires a 20 microfarad capacitor and the second a 60 microfarad capacitor. The capacitors are connected between two terminals and power is connected between one of those terminals and the third terminal. Which of the two terminals is connected to power may determine the direction of rotation. Checking the resistance between each terminal and every other terminal may confirm how the motor should be connected and whether or not it is reversible. There is no indication that the motor can be operated from 400 volts.

Comment: Hi Charles, your assumption seems to be right, I updated the description. I will accept your answer after field test.

Comment: I got the motor running so thank you for your correct answer. However your suggestions concerning capacitor seizing are wrong. 60 uF for a 230V, 0.5kW is to much. It would be roughly correct for 0.5A. Maybe you confused kW wit A ?

Comment: That was my interpretation of the information marked on the motor.